# passing anonymous functions as parameters in livescript

Tags: javascript, livescript

What's the correct way to pass a function as a parameter in liveScript?

For instance, lets say I Want to use the array reduce function, in convectional javascript I would write it as the following

```
myArray.reduce(function (a,b) {return a + b});
```

This translates to liveScript quite nicely as:

```
myArray.reduce (a,b) -> a + b
```

Now, I want to set the initial value by providing a second parameter:

```
myArray.reduce(function (a,b) {return a + b},5);
```

How would I translate this to liveScript? It seems  that the first function overrides any ability to pass additional parameters to reduce.

Apologies if I have missed something obvious, but I can't seem to find anything pertaining to this scenario in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the closure in `()`

```
[1,2,3].reduce ((a,b) -> a + b), 0
```

Compiles to

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(function(a, b){
  return a + b;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

For more complex functions I'd recommend you to use this style

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce do
  (a, b) ->
    # your code here
  0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`~`](http://livescript.net/#property-access) to bind the `this` argument, then call [`flip`](http://www.preludels.com/#flip) on it to swap the first and second parameters:

```
flip [1, 2, 3]~reduce, 0, (a, b) -> a + b
```

This may be more readable if the callback body is very long.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answer, LiveScript offers binops, just put parentheses around the operator.

```
[1 2 3].reduce (+), 0
```